# Revert to XCode 5 / iOS 7 SDK

Tags: xcode, ios8

A little background information:

I want to submit an update for my application. The update was developed for iOS 7 and works great. This week I upgraded my iPad to iOS 8 to see if the app worked there, and it did.

This morning I saw that XCode automatically updated itself to v6. I compiled the app once again (first time with iOS 8 as Base SDK) and it is awful!

Many things that worked before are bugged like

- tap outside a modal view to close it (nothing happens)
- tap back button in a modal view (this closes the modal view instead of going to the prior modal view)
- hidden table view cells that are expanded upon a button click (this closes the modal view)

I don't have the time to fix all these errors and want to launch the update as soon as possible.

Can I get back XCode 5 or install iOS 7 SDK somehow?

Comment: It's to late now mate your app has to work on iOS 8 when you submit any new apps or app updates. You can drop support for old versions of iOS but you can't drop later versions.

Comment: It works on iOS 8. It just doesn't work with iOS 8 SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall `Xcode.app` from `/Applications` and [download Xcode 5.1.1](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_5.1.1/xcode_5.1.1.dmg) from the Apple Developer Download site.